# How to bind multiple parameter to MVC Controller| restangularjs?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, restangular

I am developing an AngularJs application.The services are developed in asp.net mvc 4.

For the ajax calls, I am using restangularjs.

The server action method is like below:

```
   public AjaxResult ThirdPartyLogin(GoogleAuthResult googleAuthResult, LoginType loginType)
   {}

    public class GoogleAuthResult
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Access_Token { get; set; }
    }
```

The javascript part:

```
        rest.all('route----sample').post({
            loginType: 'Google',
            googleAuthResult: {code: '23884kjso'}
        });
```

But, the model binding is not working in action method, always getting null in all properties.

Comment: I guess you should use $http for that... restangular is prepared to deal with REST endpoints...

Comment: I've tried with customPOST method also